# Find parametric equations using parallel lines and line through a point

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

How would I find the parametric equation of a line through $(1,-1,1)$ and parallel to the line $x + 2 = 1/2y = z -3$.

Would I find the vector equation first? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

The equation: $$\frac{x + 2}{1} = \frac{y}{2} = \frac{z - 3}{1}$$
can be written as: $$\frac{x - (-2)}{1} = \frac{y - 0}{2} = \frac{z - 3}{1}$$
and hence represents the line passing through $(-2,0,3)$ with direction vector $(1,2,1)$. Since parallel lines have the same direction vector, the line you're looking for is: $$X = (1,-1,1) + t(1,2,1), \quad t \in \Bbb R.$$
To find the parametric equations, make the componentes in the left side equal to the components in the right side. (e.g.: $x = 1 + t$)